# Adobe Flash Professional not playing sound from the timeline

Tags: audio, adobe-flash, timeline

Not sure if this is the right site for this question, but here it goes.

I created a .fla file way back in 2013. When I import this file in Adobe Flash Professional (2015 release) everything works well except the audio. When I click the "Play" button on the timeline to preview it, the audio layer does not make any sound. However, the audio file works just fine when playing it from the library. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. I feel really stupid right about now.

Just go to the "Control" menu and disable the "Mute Sounds" option. I was not even aware that option was there.

[image]